# Saving the value of an array in a method

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I will just post the pseuducode, hope you will understand:

> > import java.util*.;
>
> main method {
>
> > subemethod1();

```
submethod1() {

 Screen input = new Scanner(System.in);
 int buy = input.nextInt();

  if( buy != 0) {
     submethod2();
    }

 submethod2() {
 Screen input = new Scanner(System.in);
 int[][]grid = new int [5][6]
 int row = input.nextInt();
 int col = input.nextint();
 grid[row][col] = 1;
```

Let's assume I typed 1 for row, and 1 for col this time. then `grid[1][1] = 1`. I want to save the value of `grid[1][1]` so that next time I enter row 2, col 2 I will have:

```
 grid[1][1] = 1;
 grid[2][2] = 1; and so on for whatever row-col combination I type.
```

lastly I want to return to submethod1, and I want submethod1 to understand that grid[1][1] = 1 and that grid[2][2] also has the value 1; and so on....

Answer (score 0):

This is a scoping problem. Essentially you're creating a new `int[][]` variable called `grid` every time you call `submethod2()`. Either store it as a class variable, or pass it in and then return it from `submethod2()` and manually update it yourself (I wouldn't recommend this approach)

Without more context, it's hard to recommend how to decompose your problem into [objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming), but one solution could be something like the following:

```
import java.util*.;

public class MainClass {
    private int[][] grid;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        submethod1();
    }

    private void submethod1() {
        grid = new int[5][6];
        Screen input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int buy = input.nextInt();

        if( buy != 0) {
            submethod2();
        }
    }

    private void submethod2() {
        Screen input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int row = input.nextInt();
        int col = input.nextint();
        grid[row][col] = 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below I am assuming that you are asking about saving value of grid in an instance of program and not between various instances of program calls. if you want to save value of grid between varrious program calls than you will have to store value of grid in some file etc.

instead of creating the array grid inside submethod2(), create it as a class variable and submethod1(), submethod2() as member functions.

create an object in main method and call submethod1() on the object

something like

```
class ABC
{
int[][] grid = new int[5][6];

 submethod1()
{
...
}

 submethod2()
{
 ...
 }


public static void main(String args[])
{
  ABC abc = new ABC();
  abc.submethod1();
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way to deal with such problem is use Object Oriented approach. Remember that's why we use Java.

Create a class `GridItem` which will have three properties `row`, `column`, `value`. When you store some value create object of `GridItem` and store it in Global List. You can then iterate over it in any function and access which values were stored.

```
     class GridItem
    {
        int row;
        int column;
        int value;

        public GridItem(int row, int column, int value)
        {
            this.row = row;
            this.column = column;
            this.value = value;
        }
        //Provide getters only
    }
    ArrayList<GridItem>items = new ArrayList<GridItem>();
    items.add(new GridItem(1, 1, 1));// 1 row 1 col 1 value
    items.add(new GridItem(2, 2, 2));// 2 row 2 col 2 value


    items.get(0).getRow()// get first
```

There are several other solutions. e.g Maintain a global array and then expand it. Create list of grids etc but they all are complicated and do more than necessary.